# How to increase Alexa waiting time of response from server

Tags: php, alexa-skills-kit

We have one intent that makes many requests to our server so the response might be slow. Alexa getting stop and saying the requested skill not responding.

Call back url code is in php.

Answer (score -2):

It's not possible to change alexa response waiting time. But the response you get it's not related to time issue. if it was so it would be :

```
this skill took to much to respond
```

In your case i think it's a returning response issue I mean theire is a part in your code which is unreacheable or theire is not a return statement .